# Usage of "taken" regarding the time a picture was taken

Tags: word-order, software

I'm not a native English speaker, but I have lived in the US for one year. I'm developing software (i.e. an application programming interface, API). There is one property that is supposed to store the date and time that an image was taken by the user. When I was creating the model, I came up with this name for the property: **DateTaken**.

This made total sense to me. But some coworkers asked me to change the property name to **TakenDate**. TakenDate, to me is wrong. I honestly don't know why, but it just sounds wrong when said out loud. Could someone please explain a little more?

Comment: Your coworkers have some weird ideas! But seriously, it's pointless trying to apply principles of *grammar* to database field names.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming variables is specifically off-topic.

Comment: Well, I asked the question because I specifically didn't have 100% sure if the correct form was Data taken or taken date. The variable part was only a plus to the question, a background story to describe why I was in doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an English language perspective, you are correct: *date taken*, which is short for "the date that the image was taken," is preferable over *taken date*. This has to do with how participles are used in English.

However, you have a very specific use case here. When creating field names (column names, element names, etc.), there are standard conventions that may be used that might not strictly conform to regular English syntax. In this case, you might ask your colleagues for a coding style guide. I suspect that there is a recommendation to name all fields as `[Descriptor][Noun]` or even `[Descriptor][Data_Type]`. While *TakenDate* sounds weird in English, it would fit nicely alongside *ShipmentDate*, *UploadDate*, etc. And there is probably some value in the consistency of that syntax.

Comment: Well that makes sense. I guess the problem was that I was only thinking as you said from an English language perspective. And you are correct, there is this [Descriptor][Noun] standard, which for some mysterious reason I didn't remember! Thank you.